# how to convert sequence of jpeg image into video format?

Tags: c#, windows

hi
I am developing a video capture application using C#.net. i captured 
video through webcam and saved it as a JPEG images then i want to make a 
wmv file  with those images. how can i do that what are the basic steps needed for that can any body help

Comment: Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I am working on this myself. I have found two ways that may be possible - both require the purchase of an outside library.

The first one looks to be the easiest but costs the most, although it will allow you to use it for free you will just have to deal with a pop up telling you to purchase the library: http://bytescout.com/products/developer/imagetovideosdk/imagetovideosdk_convert_jpg_to_video.html

The other involves using Microsoft Encoder 4. I am still working on this one. You can get the free version here: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18974

C# doesn't natively support much in the way of sound or video so outside reference assemblies seem to be a necessity.

Right now that is the best help I can offer until I figure it out.